# what's wrong with my collapsible navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
*<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MRA car Rental</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
         </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><a href="register.php" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Register</a></li>
         <li><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</nav>*
```

When I resize the browser and click on the button, it doesn't works. What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: have you include bootstrap.js ?

Comment: it works fine. just be sure to include bootstrap js and css + jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have boostraps js and css files you can add these to your html.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```